# Cross-interface type guards

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Say a `schema` object validates a `data` object.

Is there any kind of dark magic that would allow us to narrow down the type of a `data` property after a `schema`-based type guard?

Snippets are worth a thousand words:

```js
function validate(data: Data, schema: Schema) {}

interface Data {
  [key: string]: number | string | undefined;
}

interface Schema {
  properties: {
    [key: string]: { type: "number" | "string" } | undefined;
  };
}

// Just for demo purposes: we don't know its exact shape until run time.
const schema: Schema = {
  properties: {
    firstName: {
      type: "string",
    },
  },
};

// Idem.
const data: Data = {
  firstName: "John",
};

validate(data, schema); // What kind of magic could happen here...

if (schema.properties.firstName?.type === "string") {
  const firstName: string = data.firstName; // ...so that there's no error here?
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBNVQKYAUOUqAXIgCK6oA0iAzhABZ4C2ZiAys26gJSIA3gF8AsACgJMMPgBOwVBDyVqQiYkQBtANZ4AnuXpRZ0gOYBdcmBCsARnlmIAPg2NnnicFjzBpeLADcEmKS4tJyCkpcPOxq4hoADrJwCQ6wePTkguoaWroGriZgFlmIUHqp5ABE1nYOVR5VRkWmDcIeXj5+gTnCQeIhEgD0Q4gAUiBGiMBwjt6scIgJILIJcPQZ5ADuylgIAORQiNpgcFuIMFD0iHgAHopH9EyoqZ4yMOiIsuBlMKx4ADoJBAEFNGCx2ORuBDUIgALxxRLJVKydKZRG5XyyIwAOVQ-yyOVyZQqeGqzTMVRoRMQwmp8Vp9L6EmGowAkvMgeIQWApsQOFQSPCMVjcfiyYgqmM4EwwFTgv0JGhMMRCPy6ODeHwAogRogAOrPI7aaRYRBwYCIdimGAQRAgkDoM3PBKpJAsWSAgFcqSWgia9gApIpNIwDIA0VQPH-AD8APKrzhSclFOKVQE2QZPKmkejEtTpmF-IjMGxUfFOr13oB9EWUCNZQ9eH211ON1kyUcTZjwSAA)

I'm thinking about turning `Schema` into a class with a custom getter function that would rely on the `asserts` keyword to type the `data` property accordingly. (1) I'm not sure it's feasible and (2) there may be a better way.

Any idea?

Comment: *"we don't know its exact shape until run time"* - If you only know the shape of the object at *runtime*, how should TypeScript know that the property `firstName` exists at *compile time*?

Comment: Type guard (`if (schema.properties.firstName?.type === "string") { /* ... */ }`)

Comment: You should at least know the schema in advance for any of this to work. The fact that you are accessing `schema.properties.firstName?.type` means that you at least think it's a possibility this  property will exist, so you need to better define your schema with all possible options. Then we can talk about a type guard, which is probably doable .

Comment: I can't know more about the `schema` at compile-time than what's currently in the `Schema` interface. The `schema.properties.firstName?.type` bit is just for narrowing the problem. If this type guard works, then I can loop over the `schema` object and access corresponding `data` property values without throwing a bunch of `as` and non-null assertions.

Comment: The thing we know is that `schema` *validates* `data`. So if `schema` has some property with a `"type"` set to `"number"`, then `data` *must* have the same property and and we know for sure that it's a `number`.

Comment: TS doesn't have this kind of dynamic property naming abilities to happen; it requires something like generic values and existential types, neither of which are available.  You would have to refactor to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxDrGm) where you use a helper object or helper function to hand you correlated pairs of `type`/`data` values.  If that answers your question I can write this up; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, makes a lot of sense. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately TypeScript's type system isn't expressive enough to represent an arbitrary correlation between the properties of `schema` and those of `data`.  It would require something like *correlated unions* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), as well as "infinite" unions of every possible object type, which would be like *existential types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)... but TypeScript doesn't directly support either of these.

I'd say you need to refactor into something that encapsulates both `schema` and `data` in a single object, which exposes some method to get a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of pairs of schema type and property value.  Possibly like this:

```
function validate(data: Data, schema: Schema) {
  // do validation, and then
  return function prop(k: string) {
    return { type: schema.properties[k]?.type, data: data[k] } as
      { type: "number", data: number } |
      { type: "string", data: string } |
      { type: undefined, data: undefined }
  }
}
```

So, when you call `validate(data, schema)`, you get a validation function:

```
const vf = validate(data, schema);
```

And this function can be called for any given property:

```
const firstNameProp = vf("firstname");
```

Which is then a discriminated union of the type/data values:

```
/* const firstNameProp: {
    type: "number";
    data: number;
} | {
    type: "string";
    data: string;
} | {
    type: undefined;
    data: undefined;
} */
```

Which can be inspected the way you want:

```
if (firstNameProp.type === "string") {
  const firstName: string = firstNameProp.data;
} else {
  firstNameProp.data // number | undefined now
}
```

It's not *great*, but it's at least *possible* to represent in the type system.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ssl=52&ssc=2&pln=36&pc=1#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-Xr0GA24pcORSMUmAHBEI+fWJYmU2miAAFew2GdTkjNTdwKDb5qrisAKlQ671p97u-3GazuxmA3BzT59SbqE-SSCpCHaSNmLR5gsP4BH+EFeEBsIgVMObwtyyLjH+KHXEB15SE804kI+257g4eQFG2YYRiy0KXpGd4Tp23ZPoC0IzoRnrETYsTFEBRDYCqtFsc+JHFNIsgARCsKYTy-5GqiQA)